# django: ImportError: No module named context_processors

Tags: django

I have one django 1.9 deployment that frequently gets this error:

```
Internal Server Error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 174, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 172, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 160, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 137, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 95, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 204, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 256, in bind_template
    processors = (template.engine.template_context_processors +
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 105, in template_context_processors
    return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 105, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named context_processors
```

Here is my TEMPLATES list:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'motor/ui/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'context_processors.config',
                'ui.context_processors.navigation',
                'core.appmngr.context_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'middleware.LastSiteUrl',
]
```

Only this one site gets these error, and I have the same system deployed at multiple sites. I have verified that all the referenced context processors and middleware exists. What can I look at to track this down?

Comment: are you sure its running with the right django version? it looks like you forgot to active your virtual env or something...

Comment: inside of TEMPLATES: `'context_processors.config',` - do you have an app called like that?

Comment: @HassenPy yes, it's running 1.9, it's not a virtual env

Comment: @dahrens in the base dir of the project there is a context_processors.py that contains a config. `from context_processors import config` works.

Comment: does this import works in a django shell?

Comment: Yes, I tried all of the imports in the context_processors list in a django shell and they all work. I don't get this error all the time, just some times, but frequently.

Answer (score 0):

in your templates as above change `core.appmngr.context_processor`, 
context_processors have been moved from core to template.

```
'template.appmngr.context_processor',
```

this might work for you. read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#django-core-context-processors)

Comment: `core.appmngr` is in my project, not part of django

Comment: rename core to something else since a django module is already using the name core.

Comment: I could try that, but the django module is not being referenced at all. Also files in core/.... are referenced in 287 places in my project. I really don't want to make that many changes if it's not really an issue. So if the `django.core.appmngr.context_processor` is never referenced, why would having my own `core.appmngr.context_processor` be an issue?

Comment: try remove 'core.appmngr.context_processor' from templates then run project and see what error comes up.

Comment: Without that my app does not work properly at all. There are functions in that module that are required.